# android how to wait the result from other thread with displaying a progressdialog

Tags: android, multithreading

Could someone please tell the difference between Thread and AsynTask~
I have to this kind of thing:

```
class A{

  int nTmp;
  ClassB BTmp = new ClassB();
  ClassC CTmp = new ClassC();

//I want to put the next two lines into a separate thread, because they will consume so much time
//and I want to display a ProgressDialog when do this two lines

   Method1(nTmp, BTmp);
   CTmp = Method2();

   if(Method2(CTmp)){
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Here is my problem:

1. If I use a new Thread I can not pass the [nTmp] and [BTmp] which is belong to Class A to a separate thread.
2. Because I want to use the result from those two lines, so I have to wait the result[CTmp] in UI thread when it has to display a progressdialog.
3. I tried AsynTask, but there still is the problem 2.

I found the point for me is **how to wait the result from other thread with displaying a progressdialog**. Is there a  class could do that thing?

Comment: Here is a link which states you the clear difference (Personally the best I have seen). 
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html

Comment: I already checked that article. But there is no the introduce about how to wait another thread.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't wait for other task B to be completed, but instead task B should tell task A it finised. And depending on what your methods are intended for, there're are other features you could use for start background processing, like IntentService. Most likely AsyncTask would serve you best.

Comment: Thank you.There is no way I could just wait the UI thread using the ProgressDialog?

Comment: Because I don't have to update UI, so I think AsyncTask is not the best for me.

Comment: Not sure I understand you correctly, but the whole trick with updating UI is that you cannot do this form all the threads, not that you have to update UI just because you used AsyncTask. If I understood you correctly you need to sync both tasks, so I'd just still say again: do not wait. Let other task notify you. Just refactor your code so background task can notify main task it is done (be it with runnable, onPostExecute() or whatever way you go.